# 'hector_quadrotor' 'TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__geitem__''

Tags: ros, publisher, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was running "hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch". And I build a publisher "auto_fly", to publish message to control the quadrotor. The code is showed below:

> #!/usr/bin/env python
>
> import rospy
> from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
>
> def auto_fly():    pub= rospy.Publisher('/uav/uav2/cmd_vel',Twist,queue_size=10)
> rospy.init_node('auto_fly',anonymous=True)
> r=rospy.Rate(10) # 10Hz
>
> while not rospy.is_shutdown():
> pub.publish['x=0,y=1,z=0.2' 'x=0,y=0,z=0']
> r.sleep(1.0)
>
> if **name**== '**main**':
> try:  auto_fly()
> except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass

When I run it, it shows,

> TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

What does this error mean and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot
Glen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186871/%27hector_quadrotor%27-%27typeerror:-%27instancemethod%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27__geitem__%27%27/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error: `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` means that you're trying to use square brackets ( **getitem** ) on something that doesn't support them; namely a method.

For the publish method call, you should be using parentheses, just like any other method call in python. You'll also need to revise the argument to your publish call; it should be a python message object:

```
msg = Twist() # create a new Twist message object
msg.linear.y = 1 # set the linear y component to 1
pub.publish(msg) # publish your message
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2014-07-17**:
It works now, thanks a lot!